# Unable to run commands with "sudo" from my user

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, user-groups

For some reason, I am unable to run any commands with `su` as my user. This was working before and I'm not sure what broke it. The funny thing is that I can su to root without any problems.

Example:

```
machine:~ myuser$ who
myuser console  Sep 28 01:10 
myuser ttys000  Oct  3 22:21 
machine:~ myuser$ sudo echo "test"
Password:
su: Sorry
machine:~ myuser$ su
Password:
sh-3.2# echo "test"
test
sh-3.2# exit
exit
machine:~ myuser$
```

As far as I can tell, my user is part of the appropriate user groups (including wheel and admin):

```
machine:~ myuser$ groups myuser
staff com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 wheel everyone _appstore localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_screensharing
machine:~ myuser$ dseditgroup -o checkmember -n  . wheel
yes myuser is a member of wheel
machine:~ myuser$ dseditgroup -o checkmember -n  . admin
yes myuser is a member of admin
```

I am stumped. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this working again?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, aren't you supposed to use `sudo` to run commands, and `su` to switch users? At least, that's what I always did in Linux (not an OS X user, though I assume it's the same)...

Comment: I agree with @Bob.  sudo is used to execute a single command as another user (ie: root) while su is used to log in as another user entirely.

Comment: Argh! You're right guys, sorry about that. The same problem exists when using sudo though; I will update my question.

Comment: Argh, I'm such a noob! I got it now. I was using the wrong password for sudo. Sudo uses the admin password; not the root password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sudo` to execute a single command and use `su` to log in as another user.

Comment: Thanks Utah, this is definitely correct. However, I still have the same issue when using sudo to run single commands from my user. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Got it! I was using the wrong password (root password, instead of admin password). I will accept this as the answer, since it put me onto what I was doing wrong. Thanks again! :)

Comment: My pleasure, sir.

Comment: @Leif Specifically, it's not the "admin" password, but rather the password of the current user who is executing the command (who will usually also need to be an administrator).

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the clarification @DarthAndroid!